# "Could not find part of the path" error when copying a file

Tags: c#, path, file-copying

I've googled about this all over the Internet and still haven't found a solution. As an ultimate try, I hope someone can give me an exact answer.

I get that error when I try to copy a file from a directory to another in an File Explorer I'm trying to do on my own. It has a treeview control to browse for directories and a listview control to display the contents of the directory. This is how the code would look like, partially:

```
private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sourceDir = treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath;
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SelectedItems.Count; ++i)
        {
            ListViewItem l = listView1.SelectedItems[i];
            toBeCopied[i] = l.Text; // string[] toBeCopied, the place where I save the file names I want to save
        }
    }


private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        targetDir = treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < toBeCopied.Length; ++i)
            {
                File.Copy(sourceDir + "\\" + toBeCopied[i], targetDir + "\\" + toBeCopied[i], true);
                refreshToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.TargetSite);
        }
    }
```

The place where I got the error is at `File.Copy(sourceDir + "\\" + toBeCopied[i] ...`.

I've read that it could be something that has to do with the mapping of devices, but I don't really know what that is.

Comment: You are getting an exception that suggests there might be a problem with the path used in the File.Copy call.  Perhaps it would be worth examining the string passed in to File.Copy.  For example you could declare a local string variable, assemble the path in that string and then pass it to File.Copy.  Now you can also examine that string with the debugger, pass it to WriteLine, pass it to something from System.Debug, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not show where `toBeCopied` is created. It looks like you are probably running past the end of the values that are set in the click event, and trying to copy a bunch of files with empty names.

You should add this to the beginning of your click event

```
toBeCopied = new string[listView1.SelectedItems.Count];
```

Also (as others have noted) instead of

```
sourceDir + "\\" + toBeCopied[i]
```

you should use

```
Path.Combine(sourceDir, toBeCopied[i])
```

Comment: you were right. From your post, and some others, I managed to find out that the bound of `toBeCopied` was set and was larger than the selected items, so the function took a null argument. I edited it like this: 
`toBeCopied = new string[listView1.SelectedItems.Count];`
it was that simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Can you take a look at the [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) method on MSDN?  This will help make sure all your entire path doesn't have extra \'s where they shouldn't be.

i.e.  `Path.Combine(sourceDir, toBeCopied[i])`

If you are still getting an error, let me know what the value if the above.

Answer (score 4):

Does the target path up to the file name exist?  `File.Copy()` will not create any missing intermediate path, you would need to do this yourself.  Use the debugger to see both the source and target paths you are creating and make sure the source exists and the target exists at least up to the parent of the target file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both `sourceDir` and `targetDir` exist (which you can *and should* check), you might be doubling up a trailing `\`.  When building paths, you should use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx).

```
File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, toBeCopied[i]), Path.Combine(targetDir, toBeCopied[i]), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from Henk's loop, but I'd add the file & directory checks, since it is the path not found errors that need checking/creating that the OP has the problem with.

```
for (int i = 0; i < toBeCopied.Length; ++i)
{
    string sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourceDir, toBeCopied[i]);
    if(File.Exists(sourceFile))
    { 
        string targetFile = Path.Combine(targetDir, toBeCopied[i]);
        if(!Directory.Exists(targetDir)) 
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir); 
        File.Copy(sourceFile, targetFile, true);
    }
    refreshToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e)
}
```